# How do I resolve file permissions issue in laravel sail

Tags: php, laravel, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Every time I go to http://localhost on my browser, after running ./vendor/bin/sail up,
I keep getting this error

```
ErrorException
file_put_contents(C:\wamp64\www\catholic_group_of_schools_entrance_platform\storage\framework/sessions/NMNV89ihi6pcYr140olVDp7iPx4ed2ML4Eh8ik7q): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You have this tagged with *windows-subsystem-for-linux*, and your `./vendor/bin/sail up` is using a Linux-style path, but then the browser error that you are getting is using a Windows-style path, which makes me question whether or not WSL is really being used.  I'd kind of expect that it would be something like `/mnt/c/wamp64/www/...` if this was running under WSL.  Or perhaps that's the problem -- Your application improperly uses a Windows-style path when it should use the WSL equivalent?  Can you provide more information on how things are installed, configured, and run?

Comment: Also, the title of your question is a bit misleading.  You don't seem to be seeing a permission issue.  You are seeing a "No such file or directory", which sounds like a path issue, not permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your input @NotTheDr01ds. With your analysis, i believe everything should add up already. But lemme explain further. I am using WSL because docker desktop and laravel sail require it for windows. And I have installed ubuntu on my system via WSL. If you are familiar with laravel, you will realise that the error i posted is not from the command line but from the laravel application itself, and the storage folder in question usually needs permission for any laravel application to work correctly.

Comment: Cool - Not familiar with laravel directly, but yes, I assumed that was coming from the browser application, not the command-line.  Is there also some configuration or code in the app itself that points to that directory?  If so, then I'm hoping that replacing it with the `/mnt/c` equivalent will resolve.

Comment: Configuration or code pointing to that directory? Yes most definitely, but these codes are from laravel dependencies and core framework itself, not my codes